# Spacy inference goes OOM when processing several documents

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, spacy

I'm using spacy to process documents that come through rest api. To be more specific, I'm using transformer based model `en_core_web_trf` for NER, running on GPU. Here is a code snippet of the spacy related class (It is packed inside some basic flask server and but I don't suppose that matters here)

```
class SpacyExtractor():
    def __init__(self):
        spacy.require_gpu()
        self.model = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf',
                                 disable=["tagger", "parser", "attribute_ruler", "lemmatizer"])


    def get_named_entities(self, text: str):
        doc = self.model(text)
        entities = []
        for ent in doc.ents:
            entities.append((ent.text, ent.label_))
        return entities
```

The problem is, with each call of `get_named_entities`, the amount of GPU memory allocated goes up. And it is like 2-3 GB every time (I checked this by repeatedly calling nvidia-smi while the app was processing the docs). So after a few calls, I get OOM error
`RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.35 GiB (GPU 0; 10.76 GiB total capacity; 5.02 GiB already allocated; 1.18 GiB free; 8.41 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)`
Documents are not huge at all, 1-100 pages of text for each one.
I think I make some mistake, but I just don't see it.
Environment: Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.8, spacy 3.1.3, cuda 9.1, RTX 2080Ti 11GB RAM

EDIT: Also, I found out the OOM error when processing a single really long document, presented as a single long string.

Comment: Have you tried using `doc._.trf_data = None`, as far as I can tell this should lead to the memory being freed at some point (you could always force this by explicitly calling `gc.collect()`).

Comment: I have tried it now, but it didn't change anything (I did both, even try to add `del doc` before `gc.collect()` )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is, with each call of get_named_entities, the amount of GPU memory allocated goes up.

You should `detach` your data as explained in the [FAQ](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/faq.html):

> **Don’t accumulate history across your training loop.** By default,
> computations involving variables that require gradients will keep
> history. This means that you should avoid using such variables in
> computations which will live beyond your training loops, e.g., when
> tracking statistics. Instead, you should detach the variable or access
> its underlying data.

---

**Edit**

You can also use

```
with torch.no_grad():
    doc = self.model(text)
```

> EDIT: Also, I found out the OOM error when processing a single really long document, presented as a single long string.

Well, this is to be expected.

Comment: I'm not really sure what this `detach` and not accumulating history could mean in my case, where I use torch indirectly through spacy. The only varibale I store is `doc`, which I need for named entitites and is a spacy class.

Comment: @Honza see the edit

Comment: That solved, thanks! I think I will do bug report on spacy github, because I think that this should work "out of the box" without the need to call special torch function, since you usually don't need the gradient for inference.